# How can I adapt this selenium code so that it constantly refreshes in a loop for 'n' times?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options=Options()

driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.theguardian.com/uk")

time.sleep(2)
driver.refresh()
```

I'd like to be able to do the following with the above code:

1.Go to the url

2.Wait for page to load

3.Refresh page

4.Repeat steps 2 & 3 for 'n' number of times (let us say n=100)

Comment: Would a regular loop and `time.sleep()` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply introduce a `while loop` have put counter `i`, and set a condition that if `i == 100` (let's say), you want to come out of the loop.

**Code:**

```
i = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.refresh()
    if i == 100:
        break
    else:
        continue
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. Out of curiosity, 
Would this be an infinite loop?:

i = 0

while True:

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.refresh()

    if i <0:

        break

    else:

        continue

    i = i + 1

Comment: If you take out simply `if-else` block, it's gonna be an infinite loop.