# How can I adjust this line of selenium code to get the status info of this item?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this line of code which I am trying to use to obtain the status of an item. Here is the line of code:

```
item_status = driver.findElement(By.className("status-info")).getText();
```

I'm not sure how I can adjust this to retrieve the text seen here:

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options=Options()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

#Directing to site
driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nintendo-Switch-OLED-Model-Neon/dp/B098TNW7NM/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Nintendo+Switch&qid=1651147043&sr=8-3");
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/span/form/div[3]/span[1]/span/input"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/span/input"))).click()
```

it will click on search icon, now on the result page, this xpath `//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-success a-text-bold']` is not present hence nothing is getting printed on the console you are likely to face `TimedoutException`.

However looking at the screenshot that you've shared, I would say to use this xpath

`//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),'In stock.')]`

If you want to print the text and tag

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),'In stock.')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

If only text you want:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='availability']//span[contains(text(),'In stock.')]"))).get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Comment: I've just tried both code but both are giving me TimeoutException errors unfortunately.

Comment: Where exacly `In stock` is present, I could not locate that on UI

Comment: Apologies, I was using the wrong URL. I updated the code in the question so that I don't confuse others. Your code worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Any idea how I could loop this code?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031026/how-can-i-adapt-this-selenium-code-so-that-it-constantly-refreshes-in-a-loop-for?noredirect=1#comment127280098_72031026

Comment: I will have a look and see if I can help you there !

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElement(By.className("status-info"))` is the *Java* syntax and *`getText()`* is a *Java* method. Possibly you need *Python* syntax and method.

---

### Solution

To print the text ***In stock.*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.a-size-base.a-color-success.a-text-bold"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-success a-text-bold']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried the XPATH code but I get an error unfortunately. I've now included the full code at the top if you'd like to try,